# offshoring rendering of core text to background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I just watched one of the WWDC 2012 videos on concurrency and UIKit and it shows how you can do rendering of the image on a background thread.. basically instead of using drawRect you convert the context into an image in a background thread and then show it.

I want to achieve the same result with core text.. is this possible?

Comment: Of course.  Core Text is definitely thread-safe.  The same rules about multiple access apply though.

Comment: @CodaFi how do I then translate this? Say I have a drawTextInRect.. how do I make it render in the background?

Comment: You dispatch it.  dispatch_sync returns later, dispatch_async returns immediately.

Comment: you mean put all the code of drawTextInRect in dispatch_async?

Comment: You should look at DTCoreText - open source library to do lots of stuff with Core Text - and make your life easier.